# PIL image help (picture and text problem)

Tags: discord, bots

I need 2 help(im making a discord bot)
1.How can paste transparent background's picture?(i used to use Image paste)
2.How can i let my text (ImageFont) in my text box?

(I hope anyone could do a example)

I hope anyone could do a (or two? Cuz 2 problem?) Example for me